# Is there a proof showing super roots and super logarithms won't lead to a solution for the quintic?

Tags: tetration, hyperoperation, quintics

So I am learning about tetrations and I just learned that tetrations are not elementary functions. When I heard that I remembered back to the statement that there is no general solution to the quintic in [elementary functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) (all [hyperoperations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperoperation) up to exponentation, also radicals, logarithms, trig funcs, and others). So, I was wondering if it has been shown (a proof) that all hyperoperations and their inverses do not produce a general solution to the quintic. Or is that still an unsolved problem. Thanks!

Comment: The general quintic can be solved by linear combinations of hypergeometric functions ${}_4F_3,$ and as far as I know, there is no connection between them and tetration.  For instance, a power series involving the Lambert W has terms like $n^{-n},$ which is not a ratio of rationals $(a_1)_n..(a_m)_n/(b_1)_n ...(b_j)_n$ of any kind of hypergeometric.

Comment: A quintic has five zeros or less. While I don't agree with any extensions of super-roots or super-logarithms on the Internet,  expect super-roots and super-logarithms to be fractal with infinite zeros.